# When I start a new activity, my app crashes. How to fix that?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

```
  private void userIsLoggedIn() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

That is the code that should change the activity ^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tylerwilliams.openmessagingv2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Spectrum Messenger"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainPageActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivitys"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FindUserActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That is my manifest code, I have tried to change it but whenever I do I either make more problems or it won't work. I am pretty sure its me just being a noob and that I have got something in the manifest wrong.

Comment: have you made entry in to manifest file for MainPageActivity?

Comment: Can you show us the error ?What exactly is your error. ?

Comment: You can have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for getting the crash details and then edit your question and add the crash log. Otherwise this might just get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't believe I can see the crash logs because my AVD does not load so every time I need to test it I build it as a APK and run it on my phone..

Comment: I have also added my manifest file because I believe I just haven't done it correctly

Comment: Please show your logcat output containing the error

Comment: I don't believe I can see the logs because my AVD does not load so every time I need to test it I build it as a APK and run it on my phone..

Comment: @TylerWilliams What prevents you from getting the logs from the phone then?

Comment: You can get logs from a phone when connected via a USB cable with USB debugging enabled in developer mode.